# Time Label in NetBeans?

Tags: java, datetime, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have added a label for time,date using,
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
             DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

```
   Date date = new Date();
   d.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   t.setText(dateFormat1.format(cal.getTime()));
```

But they don't change. I mean I want to work it as a clock. work seconds. changing it every time. How to do this???
Thank You.

Comment: By the way, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a java.util.Timer and then update the text box at what ever interval you decide.

You can also use cal.getTime() (which returns a Date object) for both text boxes as the Date object in Java contains both date and time elements. It will also mean you have a more accurate set of information

Comment: `java.util.Timer` should not be used with Swing as it violates the single thread rules of Swing.